# NX + Nest.js + TypeORM - Webpack + Migrations

Tags: typescript, webpack, nestjs, typeorm, nrwl-nx

So, I've started a project using NX (Nest.js + Angular). I need a database, so I've configured TypeORM. Everything works fine in a "serve" mode, but, how should I configure migrations?

In a regular Nest.js project, everything in a `dist` directory has the same structure as your project, so also migrations are compiled and copied there. So if you have TypeORM configured properly, having your `migrationsRun` flag set to `true` and having `migrations` path set correctly, migrations are run on the app start.

Problem is, that `NX` uses `webpack` so you don't have a whole structure in `dist` but just one single `main.js` file and nothing else. Migration files are not copied there.

My question is then: what's the best way to solve it? Should I try to reconfigure webpack? Or there is a better way for that?

My project's structure looks more or less like this:

```
project/
├─ apps/
│  ├─ api/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  │  ├─ config/
│  │  │  │  ├─ database/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ typeorm.config.ts
│  │  │  ├─ database/
│  │  │  │  ├─ migrations/
|  |  |  |  |  ├─ 1668904379611-SomeMigration.ts
├─ dist/
│  ├─ apps/
│  │  ├─ api/
│  │  │  ├─ main.js
```

`typeorm.config.ts`

```
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  port: +process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
  username: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: [__dirname + '/../../**/database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  },
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: true,
  logging: true,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
```

//edit

I figured out that it's a problem with Webpack, not NX itself. Webpack bundles everything into one main.js file.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue ussing webpack.
According to the typeorm [FAQ documentation](https://typeorm.io/faq#bundling-migration-files) you should use a specific configuration for webpack.
This work if you have "simple" migration files, only composed of SQL and not entities ( like in seed migration for exemple ). It becomes harder with more complex files.

You can use [webpack-merge plugin](https://npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge) to build differently your main.js and each migration files and keep one webpack.config file.

Do not forgot that migration files are in JS now. You should adapt the code for production. Particulary with the typeorm CLI and datasource path.

**I suggest you to read [another post about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66169705/bundle-a-nestjs-typeorm-application-with-webpack)**

I hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

So in my project we had general config for database in a folder called lib which was generated through **NX** command, and for each service we get the general config from lib and the migration of each service from it's own config. and then  we have defined some target in package.json to run migrations.

// Module of service
[image]

// dataStoreOptions.ts
[image]

// project.json
[image]

**Hint:** The project was a mono repo so each service had it's own package.json so for each service which has database we put these targets to it's own package.json file.

I hope this be helpful.

Comment: Well, I have it done in a similar way, but my only question is, how should you copy migration files into dist? I see you didn't put a general "regex" migration path, but just a migration class itself. I didn't check this way, it  probably would work, but putting every single migration here in this array may be a bit tedious 

Comment: Yeah, I confirm, this way it bundles migrations into `main.js` file, but I don't like this solution to have all migrations added manually

Comment: @alanmcknee Actually typeORM can not automatically add migration files, because of that when creating new migrations the new migration file name must add to array manually. I could not find a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Well, it can, it's called `glob pattern`. You can set it like I did in my post, `migrations: [__dirname + '/../../**/database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}']`. Thanks for trying anyway!